# push and pop item in array on onchange event :javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, checkbox

I am working with the datatable, where data filled from api service.

I am adding checkboxes to eash row in action column.

When i click checkbox is checked, the value of that specific record passed to javascript function using 'onchange' event.

Same with the uncheck function.

**Sample Script**

```
//checkbox added to each row holding unique id(ignored mentioning variables)
var passingId,orgName;
var dataList=[];

<td><input type="checkbox" id=passingId onchange="checkThis(passingId + ',' + orgName )"/></td>

function checkThis(ids, oName) {
            var el = document.getElementById(ids);
            if (el.checked) {
                $.post("demo_test_post.asp",
                {
                    OId: ids,
                    ONAme: oName
                });
                var listItemAdd = oName;
                dataList.push(listItemAdd);
                alert(dataList);
            }
            else if (!el.checked) {
                $.post("demo_test_post.asp",
                {
                    OId: ids,
                    ONAme: oName
                });
                var listItemRemove = oName;
                dataList.pop(listItemRemove);
                alert(dataList);
            }
        }
```

This method push data to array when any record is check.

When unchecked, the record of that row(oName only in this case) must be removed from array.

> Adding part has no problem, removing part is working but not removing
>   selected value but removes last stored value. I am surely missing
>   something, as i am new to javascript can't understand the examples.

If someone can help, please do help.Thanks for your time.

Comment: `dataList` is an array, right?

Comment: @LiranBo yes, var dataList=[];  thanks for noticing, updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do, is replace the `pop` to splice, in order to do so, you need to find the removed element index in the array.

```
function checkThis(ids, oName) {
            var el = document.getElementById(ids);
            if (el.checked) {
                $.post("demo_test_post.asp",
                {
                    OId: ids,
                    ONAme: oName
                });
                var listItemAdd = oName;
                dataList.push(listItemAdd);
                alert(dataList);
            }
            else if (!el.checked) {
                $.post("demo_test_post.asp",
                {
                    OId: ids,
                    ONAme: oName
                });
                var removeItemIndex = dataList.indexOf(oName);
                if (removeItemIndex != -1) dataList.splice(removeItemIndex, 1);  //remove at this index - remove 1
                alert(dataList);
            }
        }
```

You can read more about splice [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp)

Answer (score 2):

`pop` is a **[Stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type))** operation, which removes last element of the array. Instead you should use something like search the given element and remove it, as shown below

```
var listItemRemove = oName;
var index = dataList.indexOf(listItemRemove);
if(index >= 0) dataList.splice(index, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Array.pop() always removes the last element in the array.  In order to remove a specific element you must search for it and remove it.  This can be done using Array.indexOf to find the index of the element and Array.splice to remove it.

```
var index = dataList.indexOf(listItemRemove);
if (index !== -1){
    dataList.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Alternatively you could use the Array.filter function to remove all elements matching the search item.

```
dataList = dataList.filter(function(element){
    return element !== listItemRemove;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ve8puvk3/

Comment: thank you for your value able input, +1 for correct implementation